# Compress short fixed length string (52 characters) down to less than 40

Tags: c++, compression

I tried googling for an algorithm to compress/encrypt a shor fixed size string from 52 characters down to 40 but can't seem to find any.

Target strings are random alphanumeric [A-Z0-9]
e.g "M5KS07VHN2X42JCY1PFHE1ZZGI2XUBDFAKQBEPFB7CH4SECXHJXL"

I have tried huffman and smaz (https://github.com/antirez/smaz") and both inflated to size of the original string.

Does anyone know a good algorithm for such purpose?

Comment: I don't think any compression is going to guarantee a certain % for any arbitrary input. If you need a rock solid guarantee to get 52 to under 40 losslessly you might be in trouble.

Comment: @Dave: Unless you know the input is alphanumeric, so that each character can be represented by 6 bits.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework or interview question or so? Given that the result of the naive approach to map things to Nbit numbers fits so good into the 40 bytes requirement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a A-Z0-9, the simplest encoding is simply to encode as 6 bits per character (which would potentially allow for more. 52 characters is 52 * 8 bits, the compressed string will be 52 * 6 = 39 bytes.

Edit: A slightly more complex system would be to store using the [RADIX-50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50) format used by DEC in their PDP-11 and similar systems, which would store 3 characters in 16 bits, by using a multiplier of 40 for each character. I used this system when I was a student and the school had a PDP-11 running RSTS/E.

Comment: Note: they called it RADIX-_50_ because the 50 is actually an octal number, equal to 40 in decimal.  Related joke: There are 10 kinds of people in the world: those that understand binary, and those that don't.

Comment: Related joke #2: Why do programmers confuse Halloween and Christmas? Because OCT 31 == DEC 25.